# Forward from a Managedbean to another Managedbean with jsf

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

i want to know how could i redirect from a function in a managed bean to another like that

bean 1 with the function A() -------> call bean 2 with function B() ------> function B() will call at the end the jsf page.

Comment: You could do this if all the beans involved were in the correct scope.

Answer (score 0):

I really not sure what you are trying to get here.. Look at the method, This method can give you a bean instance by String... So you can get Bean B when you are in Bean A and use its methods..

My suggestion is just to use Utils with static methods.. if this is your meaning.

```
public static Object getManagedBean(final String beanName) {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Object bean;

    try {
        ELContext elContext = fc.getELContext();
        bean = elContext.getELResolver().getValue(elContext, null, beanName);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw new FacesException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    if (bean == null) {
        throw new FacesException("Managed bean with name '" + beanName
            + "' was not found. Check your faces-config.xml or @ManagedBean annotation.");
    }

    return bean;
    }
```